# webClient Exception in .net

Tags: webclient, elasticsearch-net

I simply request(to elasticsearch) in browser fine:[image]

in .Net, I want to post same request and expected to get json data seem in pic above, but here is the exception.:[image]

What is the point of this failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `UploadString()`? Simply invoke `DownloadString()` for the entire URL and you'll be good to go:

```
var data = webc.DownloadString("http://localhost/.../ability");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use DownloadString method instead of UploadString:

```
var asd = webc.DownloadString("http://localhost:9200/dota2/_mapping/agust/field/ability");
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding more information, like: What's the difference? How does it help? Where do one find additional information on your suggestion?

Comment: hello, it was the first answer by Anton same true and accepted so ı change it but thanks for help.